# Angular 14 Angular Material Themes - 'Can't find stylesheet to import' in Visual Studio, but builds with 'ng build'

Tags: angular, angular-material, scss-mixins

I have an Angular 14 app which is built as part of an existing ASP.NET MVC Core app in Visual Studio. The angular project is a folder in the existing MVC application, so my project looks a little like this:

```
.
├── Program.cs
├── Startup.cs
├── Controllers
├── Views
├── ...
├── Angular
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── src
│   ├── content
│   │   └── styles
│   │       ├── styles.scss
│   │       └── _palette.scss
│   ├── angular.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── package.json
```

This has all worked well up to the point of adding angular material themes. Adding a theme as below in styles.scss:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@import '@angular/material/_theming';
@import '_palette.scss'; 

$Angular-primary: mat-palette($palette-primary, 500);
$Angular-accent: mat-palette($palette-secondary, 500);

$Angular-theme: mat-light-theme($Angular-primary, $Angular-accent);

@include angular-material-theme($Angular-theme);
```

This throws an `Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.` error on the `@angular/material` component in Visual Studio. Easy, reference it directly with `@use '../../node_modules/@angular/material' as mat;`, and use the same for the _theming stylesheet with `@import '../../node_modules/@angular/material/_theming';` But this then throws another error if the referenced stylesheets:

```
Error       Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use '@angular/cdk';
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  Angular\node_modules\@angular\material\core\style\_menu-common.scss 1:1  @forward
  Angular\node_modules\@angular\material\_index.scss 33:1                  @use
  Angular\Content\styles\styles.scss 1:1                                  root stylesheet
```

Angular/cdk is in my package references and exists in the node_modules. It seems that any stylesheets referencing `@angular/*` don't resolve correctly, even referenced stylesheets in the node_modules folder. I've attempted to add the `includePaths` config into my angular.json but with no effect (I've tried node_modules, ./node-modules, ./node-modules/@angular):

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../wwwroot/Angular",
        "index": "./src/index.html",
        "main": "./src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "./src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "./src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "styles": [
          "./Content/styles/styles.scss"
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "./node-modules"
          ]
        }
        ...
```

All included node packages in typescript (including `@angular/material`) build correctly, but not those referenced in .scss files.

What's interesting is that if I call `ng serve` from the /Angular folder, `ng serve` builds the app correctly and the styles (including my custom theme and palette) work as expected. It seems that Visual Studio can't resolve the path for scss files, but calling ng build directly can. Both visual studio and ng build work for the typescript references.

In ts.config I can add paths aliases like so for use in .ts files:

```
"paths": {
  "@components/*": [ "./app/components/*" ],
  "@models": [ "./app/models/index.ts" ],
  ...
```

And I effectively need something like that for the stylesheets to reference the styles found in the node_modules. I thought the `includePaths` `in angular.json` might have been an equivalent, but it doesn't appear to do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this? I'm suffering with the same issue!

Comment: @JamesBarrett No, I'm still stuck on this. Running `npm run build` works and compiles the bundles, so for now I'm just doing that, then copying in the bundled main.css and importing that directly. It works, it just means that to update the styles I need to un-comment all the above code, generate the main.css, then comment it out and copy the new main.css in. Far from ideal.